# Vue 3 ToggleEvent on details tag

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vuejs3

I am trying to leverge the `<details></details>` html tag in my vue project. There should be a [ToggleEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ToggleEvent) that fires when the [details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) tag is clicked. The event should have the properies `newState` and `oldState`. However, I can't access these properies on the event I get back.

Here is a quick example:

```js
<template>
  <details @toggle="onMyToggle">
    <summary>My Title</summary>
    Details....
  </details>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
function onMyToggle(e: ToggleEvent) {
  console.log(e);

  if (e.newState === "open") {
    console.log("It's open now!");
  } else {
    console.log("It's closed now!");
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

I am using vue 3.3.4 with TypeScript 5.2 and have tested this on Chrome 117 and FireFox 118. The browser versions tested are supposed to have support for this event. Vue seems to be passing the event to the handler function because I can log the event to the console, but the logged event is missing the `newState` and `oldState` properies.

Here is the console log of the event:

```
toggle { target: details, isTrusted: true, srcElement: details, currentTarget: details, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, returnValue: true, defaultPrevented: false, composed: false, … }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try derive the new state from the open property of the details element, and manage the old state within your `Vue component`.

Here's how you can modify your code to track and log the old and new states:

```js
<template>
  <details @toggle="onMyToggle">
    <summary>My Title</summary>
    Details....
  </details>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

const isOpen = ref(false); // track the state

function onMyToggle(e: Event) {
  const detailsElement = e.target as HTMLDetailsElement;

  if (detailsElement.open) {
    console.log("It's open now!");
    if (!isOpen.value) {
      console.log("It was previously closed.");
      isOpen.value = true;
    }
  } else {
    console.log("It's closed now!");
    if (isOpen.value) {
      console.log("It was previously open.");
      isOpen.value = false;
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Im y above solution we can make use of  `Vue's ref function` to keep track of the state of the details element (whether it's open or closed).

Then, using the `onMyToggle function`, we're checking the open property of the details element to determine its current state. After that we then use the `isOpen ref` to determine the previous state and then update it accordingly.

If you go about it this way, you'd be able to determine both the current and the previous state of the details element whenever it's toggled.

Just my 2cents. Hope it helps

Happy Coding =)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This worked to get the behavior I was looking for. I can't upvote the solution otherwise I would!